# Django - save float as INT to model

Tags: python, django, django-models

Through serializer I am saving numbers like 56.234677 to `FloatField`,
but I want to change that and save them as `int`.

I could change it before it's passed into serializer but not sure that's practical.

Can something like this be used on model input just before it's saved?:

```
def iround(x):    
    return int(round(x) - .5) + (x > 0)
```

(rounds float/decimal to int)

Comment: Why don't you use `round(int(number))`? ([more here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do something to your "number attribute" before you save it (in django models). Like this (overriding default `save` method):

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    field_x_float = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=4)
    field_x_int = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=0)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.field_x_int = round(int(self.field_x_float))
        super(SomeModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

What happens is when you save this model, django-models will "grab" the value of the `field_x_float`, will round it and finally will store the value in `field_x_int`, this way you can keep both "int" (decimal) and float version of the number (not sure if you wanted this).

**Note:** You might have to change a [`FloatField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FloatField) to a [`DecimalField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DecimalField) if you want to start use "integers" (for what I understand, in this case, you want Decimals).